# Count each condition within group

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, aggregate-functions

For every unique `GroupId` I would like to get a count of each `IsGreen`, `IsRound`, `IsLoud` condition and a total number of rows.

*Sample data:*

```
-----------------------------------------------------
 id | ItemId | GroupId | IsGreen | IsRound | IsLoud
----+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------
  1 |  1001  |    1    |    0    |    1    |    1
  2 |  1002  |    1    |    1    |    1    |    0
  3 |  1003  |    2    |    0    |    0    |    0
  4 |  1004  |    2    |    1    |    0    |    1
  5 |  1005  |    2    |    0    |    0    |    0
  6 |  1006  |    3    |    0    |    0    |    0
  7 |  1007  |    3    |    0    |    0    |    0
```

*Desired result:*

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 GroupId | TotalRows | TotalGreen | TotalRound | TotalLoud
 --------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------
    1    |     2     |     1      |     2      |     1
    2    |     3     |     1      |     0      |     1
    3    |     2     |     0      |     0      |     0
```

I'm using the following code to create the table, the problem I'm having is that if any of the groups have no rows that match one of the conditions that group does not appear in the final table. What is the best way to accomplish what I want to do?

```sql
SELECT total.GroupId
     , total.[Count] AS TotalRows
     , IsGreen.[Count] AS TotalGreen
     , IsRound.[Count] AS TotalRound
     , IsLoud.[Count] AS TotalLoud
FROM (
    SELECT GroupId
         , count(*) AS [Count]
    FROM TestData
    GROUP BY GroupId
) TotalRows
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT GroupId
         , count(*) AS [Count]
    FROM TestData
    WHERE IsGreen = 1
    GROUP BY GroupId
) IsGreen ON IsGreen.GroupId = TotalRows.GroupId
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT GroupId
         , count(*) AS [Count]
    FROM TestData
    WHERE IsRound = 1
    GROUP BY GroupId
) IsRound ON IsRound.GroupId = TotalRows.GroupId
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT GroupId
         , count(*) AS [Count]
    FROM TestData
    WHERE IsLoud = 1
    GROUP BY GroupId
) IsLoud ON IsLoud.GroupId = TotalRows.GroupId
```

Comment: Why isn't this a simple `group by groupID` and a `count` and `sum?`

Comment: Your code would work fine if you changed all the INNER JOINs to LEFT OUTER JOINs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `count` to count rows per each `[GroupId]` and `sum` to count each property .

```
select [GroupId]
     , count([GroupId]) as [TotalRows]
     , sum([IsGreen]) as [TotalGreen]
     , sum([IsRound]) as [TotalRound]
     , sum([IsLoud]) as [TotalLoud]
from [TestData]
group by [GroupId]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `conditional Aggregate`. Try this.

```
SELECT GroupId,
       Count(GroupId) TotalRows,
       Count(CASE WHEN IsGreen = 1 THEN 1 END) TotalGreen,
       Count(CASE WHEN IsRound = 1 THEN 1 END) TotalRound,
       Count(CASE WHEN IsLoud = 1 THEN 1 END) TotalLoud
FROM   tablename
GROUP  BY GroupId
```

Comment: `case` expression it kinda superfluous in this situation.