# SQL server for each distinct different sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get a list which contains the name of distinct countries, the number of their employees for each country distinctly. I can not use a for each loop in SQL server. IS there any way to achieve what I want? I can use where country='input country', but I do not want to do it for every country.

```
Select   distinct Country,
     SUM(Test.[Number of Manager]) over () AS 'Number of Parts Staff/Manager',
     Count(Test.[Name]) over () AS 'Number of Test'

From Test;
```

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY Country`

Comment: And why should you down vote the question? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I see a lot of 'rtfm' questions get downvoted, perhaps this is the reason...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count each condition within group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866592/count-each-condition-within-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `DISTINCT`, instead you should `GROUP BY`:

```
Select Country,
       SUM([Number of Manager]) AS 'Number of Parts Staff/Manager',
       Count([Name]) AS 'Number of Test'
From Test
GROUP BY Country
```

Comment: There's no way that error message can come from the SQL I show above. Please make sure you changed your `SUM` and `COUNT` lines to match. So remove the `OVER ()` part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`group by`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
SELECT Country,
       SUM([Number of Manager]) AS 'Number of Parts Staff/Manager',
       Count([Name]) AS 'Number of Test'
FROM Test
GROUP BY Country;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Country,
     SUM(Test.[Number of Manager]) OVER () AS 'Number of Parts Staff/Manager',
     COUNT(Test.[Name]) OVER () AS 'Number of Test'
FROM Test
GROUP BY Country
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using **`PATITION BY`**

```
Select   Country,
     SUM(Test.[Number of Manager]) over (partition by Country order by Country) AS 'Number of Parts Staff/Manager',
     Count(distinct Test.[Name]) over (partition by Country Country) AS 'Number of Test'

From Test;
```

or much simple way using  **`Group By COUNTRY`**

```
select country,Count(distinct Test.[Name]) AS 'Number of Test', SUM(Test.[Number of Manager]) AS 'Number of Parts Staff/Manager' from test
group by country
```